# Viena SoundFont Editor does not load large wave-Files

Tags: audio, midi, wav, sound-editing

I am playing around with the [Viena SoundFont Editor](http://www.synthfont.com/Viena_news.html) (Versions 0.935 and 0.940) and I was able to add smaller audio samples to a newly created soundbank. When I am trying to load a large sample > 400kB Viena shows a dialog with the error "File could not be read". I have not found anything about an upper duration or file size limit in the documentation.
I also wanted to see if the wav-file was of a non-standard format (they were created under MacOSX), so I tried using an .aif-sample as a starting point, converted it to wav using ffmpeg and I then tried to load this one into Viena, but it failed with the same error message.

Could anyone help me towards a solution, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent an email to the developer of Viena and asked the question above. It turns out that there is no limitation on file size or sample duration.

However, soundbanks do only allow mono and stereo samples whereas I tried to load 5.1 surround sounds (6 channels). After using ffmpeg to convert the original samples, everything worked well.

The command that I used for the conversion, is

```
ffmpeg -i surround.wav -ac 2 stereo.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try using another software, [polyphone](http://www.polyphone.fr/).
still in beta but it's worth a try

Comment: what are the advantages of this software vs the one the QA is using? why is it worth a try? please be clear on your answers and try to elaborate them further instead of writing 1 single line.

Comment: woh sorry for my single line. I find Polyphone easy to use, and the interface is really clean. Moreover there are convenient tools to edit all samples of an instrument quickly. The best is a try